# Neo4j - convert set of node's attributes from string to int

Tags: string, neo4j, integer, cypher

If I have a set of nodes with the same attributes in Neo4j, is there a way to convert the type of a certain attribute from string to int (or vice versa) for all of those nodes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about

```
MATCH (n:Type)
WHERE <filter if required>
SET n.strProp = toInt(n.strProp)
```

and

```
MATCH (n:Type)
WHERE <filter if required>
SET n.intProp = toString(n.intProp)
```